# wordpress local migration error

Tags: wordpress, migration, localhost, wamp

I'm trying to migrate my wordpress site to a WAMP hosted localsite so I can have a safe environment to edit the site and learn how wordpress works properly. (before I decided to do this had to rebuild this site from memory 3/4 times because I'm an idiot who didn't realise that backing up is my best friend)

this is my live website

http://guitarlessonswithmax.com/

Using the following youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8LgYkfnJpc

I managed to get my wordpress sort of working using WAMP but not to the desired outcome as you can see in the screenshots provided in the imgur album

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjirS.jpg

So as you can see the content is sort of there but minus the wordpress formatting which you can see on the live site.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Specially if you are using WP you need to create a Virtual Host [See this answer for how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) Then install your wordpress into the Virtual Host. Then all the relative links/references will work as they do on your live site

Comment: This is probably better asked on the wordpress.stackexchange.com site

Comment: You must also amend the database to use the new URL [see the WP site for details of how to move a WP site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: Thanks for informing me about wordpress.stackexchange.com I didn't know it existed :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I did update the database to the new URL however the link you posted about the virtual host looks like exactly what I need, Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

F12 in your browser to bring up the developer console. You can probably see a lot of '404 not found errors' where your installation expects files.

Install PhpMyAdmin and enter your database. Check the table wp_options. There should be two entries (siteurl and home ), ensure they are correct for your local installation.

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler if you use WPTunnel for this purpose.

It creates a local WordPress installation inside a Docker container and proxies it to **yoursubdomain.wptunnel.com**:

https://github.com/dsdenes/wptunnel

disclamier: I'm the author of the library